# FCM rejects push to Android device with message "restricted key "aps""

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Everything is worked for about an year and from tonight push messages stopped working.
The log on the server says:

```
rejectionReason="InvalidParameters: "aps" key is not permitted"
```

There was no update neither on server neither to an application. The question is how it is possible that FCM got broken without updating or any other action?
Also, "aps" is NOT appears on FCM documentation under restricted keys. Did someone faced this problem?

Comment: show your code then only we can help you

Comment: Having the same issue. I haven't been able to find any documentation or warning about the situation yet!.

Comment: @MustafaDüman I've spent whole day, and now received an answer from google developers on google-groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the answer of Google developer from https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/QnrMSksVziQ/m/iLeJ-WFPAQAJ
it is an Google's known issue and the fix is being rolled out.
Update:
fixed today 22 Jan 2021. The issue is resolved.